# Json array sorting based on date/time present in it

Tags: java, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to sort an json array in a json string in descending order. Currently i am writing an utility myself, which parses through the given json, takes up the array to be sorted in it. Sort the same, construct json string with sorted array and return back the json string.

Example my input json looks like below:

```
{
  "scan_detail": [
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "664",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-02 01:02:53"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-02 01:40:34"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-03 13:51:59"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-08 12:45:36"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "954",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-08 13:11:39"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-02 01:02:53"
    }
  ]
}
```

My ouput should be like below:

```
{
  "scan_detail": [
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "954",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-08 13:11:39"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-08 12:45:36"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-03 13:51:59"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-02 01:40:34"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "664",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-02 01:02:53"
    },
    {
      "refno": "8242433485",
      "status_code": "108",
      "updated_date": "2019-04-02 01:02:53"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am doing as below:

1. Convert json string to Map.
2. Pick up array to be sorted from the map.
3. Sort it by overriding Comparator.
4. overwrite sorted array back to Map
5. Covert map to json using gson.

But, in this case, i should know the complexity of the input json. I should know the path of the array in the json to sort the same.

I want to write some generic utility to sort the given array in given json string. Is there a better way to do it? Kindly suggest. Below is my code snippet, which i have tried.

```
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, Object> createHashMapFromJsonString(String json) {

//this retuns the map constructed out of given json

return map;
    }

    public String convertMapToJson(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> jsonMap){
        //this constructs json with given map using gson library
    }

    public String sortJsonArray(String UnsortedJson){
        String sortedJson = "";
        try {
            //pick up the arrar from the map given out of createHashMapFromJsonString. Sort it by overriding the comparator method. Add the sorted same to map.

// Convert the map to json using convertMapToJson.
        return sortedJson;
    }

    public Comparator<Map<String, Object>> mapComparator = new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
        public int compare(Map<String, Object> m1, Map<String, Object> m2) {
            return getEventDate(m2.get("updated_date").toString()).compareTo(getEventDate(m1.get("updated_date").toString()));
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you considered deserializing your JSON into Java objects via libraries such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)? Doing so would allow you to use / implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to sort your deserialized collections with relatively few lines of code.

Comment: Is this a one time only? Maybe you could sort your JSON using https://codeshack.io/json-sorter/ based on your key 'updated_date' ?

Comment: @AustinSchäfer, I want to sort given array in any given json. So, in this way i would need to know the path of the json array in advance and write code for the same. I want to do this in some way generic so, if i mention path of array in json and element to be used in it for sorting. My code should sort the json and ouput the json.

Comment: @marcoverbeek, No its not one-time. I should do this for numerous jsons in my framework.

Comment: Can any available Json transformation library like Jolt or something can help here? Like: Specify my output json spec in specification file and pass input json to get expected json? I am not sure. Any light on this?

Comment: @ANITHA Either you know the structure of your incoming JSON objects and are therefore able to write POJOs for them, deserialize them, and compare, or you don't, and you don't have any good way to sort them, save for searching for a limited list of field names and using their values to sort, and simply throwing an exception if that fails. I strongly recommend against the latter approach. I'm unaware of Jackson or any other library being able to create Object classes with generically created fields as the JSON objects are deserialized.

Comment: Thanks @AustinSchäfer . My requirement is to write an utility to sort any given array in a given json as i don't know json structure now. But, when services team run my framwerok, before they run they will know the json structure and array in it to be looked for sorting. Based on which they can provide any defined config file and my same underlying framework code should read those config and sort and output json.

Comment: Then my advice, if I understand correctly (that the services team decides what the JSON structure will be), is to coordinate with the services team, and ask them for the JSON structure(s) they will be using. This will let you simplify your development via Jackson and Comparable.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer there can 1000's of Jsons which will be coming in, in future as and when new backend gets added. So, as of now even services team will not be aware of json structures. So, i was trying to write some generic framework to do this. So, it fits in for all jsons with some config changes, when required to run and no code change required at all.

Comment: Found [this](https://nickolasfisher.com/blog/How-to-Dynamically-Deserialize-JSON-In-Java-With-Jackson), which may be of interest. You'll need dynamic deserialization if your teams can't adhere to a smaller set of objects or refactor the JSON bodies to use common field names such as "property" and "value" in an array format (which would let you deserialize into a single object type, where you could then check the values against whatever field name you actually needed.